# Sending a POST request using one of seven available search fields with @RequestParam to retrieve records from mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

In my app:

1. After opening a browser, user can use seven search fields, but doesn’t have to complete each one of them. Each field corresponds to one characteristic feature of the searched object.
2. A POST request is sent to the server (the html responsible for this and the previous step is shown below):

```
<main>
    <section>
        <form name="searchForm" th:action="@{'/myObjectsSearch'}" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" id="inputName" th:name="name" minlength="3">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" id="inputColor" th:name="color" minlength="3">
            </fieldset>

            <!--five more fieldsets-->

        </form>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div th:each="myObject: ${myObjects}"><p th:text="${myObject}"></p></div>
    </section>
</main>
```

3. The request first goes to the method getByDifferentParameters() in controller - *@RequestParam (required = false)* annotations were used, because not every feature will be completed by the user:

```
   @PostMapping()
   public String getByDifferentParameters(
     @RequestParam(name = "name", required = false) String name, 
     @RequestParam(name = "color", required = false) String color, 
     //five more , 
     Model model) {

        List<MyObject> myObjects = dbService.retrieveByDifferentParameters(name, color, //five more);
        model.addAttribute("myObjects", myObjects);
        return "myObjectsSearch";
    }
```

4. ... then the request goes to service and to class implementing the CrudRepository interface:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyObject> retrieveByDifferentParameters(@RequestParam(value = "NAME", required = false) String name, 
        @RequestParam(value = "COLOR", required = false) String color, //five more);
```

5. ... to finally send a query to the database from the domain class in the form of:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "MyObject.retrieveByDifferentParameters",
        query = "SELECT * FROM myObjects WHERE " + 
                "IFNULL(:name, name) = IFNULL(name, name) AND " +
                "IFNULL(:color, color) = IFNULL(color, color) AND " +
                //five more
                ;",
        resultClass = MyObject.class
)
```

The query from point 5) works perfect from the console, but not from the browser.

Should I somehow pass null value to RequestParams for mySQL to understand the query? Unless null value is already being passed to query and the issue lies somewhere else.

*PS
there are 7 features, hence the repeated comment "//five more" to save some space*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to build search&filter API. One of the best ways we've done this is to use Java Specification API with JPA. Baeldung has a great guide on this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Guide looks great, although I have a problem understanding method isOrPredicate() from class UserSpecificationsBuilder - IDE says 'Cannot resolve method 'isOrPredicate' in 'SearchCriteria''. Do you know by any chance what should be its body?

Comment: I don't have a screenshot of what you are seeing in your IDE but if it's IntelliJ maybe try invalidating cache and restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

As per answer suggested from Frantz Romain, I would like to give some hints/ easy implementation, to solve your issue on (7 search fields),

I have 3 search fields, so I have made 3 methods, and 4th method to combine them, please know the usage of

```
criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
```

It returns true if we don't have values/ if null

please refer the below code.

```
public class PostSpecification implements Specification<Post> {

    @Override
    public Specification<Post> and(Specification<Post> other) {
        return Specification.super.and(other);
    }

    @Override
    public Specification<Post> or(Specification<Post> other) {
        return Specification.super.or(other);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Post> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        return null;
    }

    public static Specification<Post> bySearch(String search) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (search == null) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            query.distinct(true);
            Predicate titlePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("title"), "%" + search + "%");
            Predicate contentPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("content"), "%" + search + "%");
            Predicate authorPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("author"), "%" + search + "%");

            Join<Post, Tag> postTagsTable = root.join("tags", JoinType.INNER);
            Predicate tagPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(postTagsTable.get("name"), "%" + search + "%");

            return criteriaBuilder.or(titlePredicate, contentPredicate,
                    authorPredicate, tagPredicate);
        };
    }
    public static Specification<Post> byPublished() {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("isPublished"),true);
    }


    public static Specification<Post> byAuthorNames(String[] authorNames) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (authorNames == null || authorNames.length == 0) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            return root.<String>get("author").in(authorNames);
        };
    }

    public static Specification<Post> byTagNames(String[] tagNames) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (tagNames == null || tagNames.length > 0) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            Join<Post, Tag> postTagsTable = root.join("tags", JoinType.INNER);
            return postTagsTable.<String>get("name").in(tagNames);
        };
    }

    public Specification<Post> findByFilters(String search, String[] authorNames, String[] tagNames) {
        return byPublished()
                .and(bySearch(search))
                .and(byAuthorNames(authorNames))
                .and(byTagNames(tagNames));
    }
}
```

You will need to add 7 different types of such functions
and call from controller or serviceImpl like this way

```
PostSpecification postSpecification = new PostSpecification();
Specification<Post> filteredSpecification = postSpecification.findByFilters(search, authorNames, tagNames);

posts = postRepository.findAll(filteredSpecification, pageable).getContent();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Shyam, this may be it though I still have to work on my controller and html. As I am using seven search fields in html I am not sure of how the 'bySearch' method from PostSpecification should be implemented in my post-method in controller, could you explain that in more detail?